# Thymeleaf 3 converts javascript properties to lowercase

Tags: javascript, json, thymeleaf

I recently migrated a project from Thymeleaf 2 to version 3, and i'm experiencing the following issue:

I have a `<script>` containing variables populated by inlining view object, this way:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/   
    window.gtmEventsDataLayer = /*[[${gtm.events}]]*/'';
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

where `${gtm.events}` is a list of objects build like this:

```
public class GTMEvent {

    private String selector;
    private String DOMEvent;
    private String GTMEvent;
    private String GTMLabel;
}
```

However, the page is being rendered with the object property names converted to lowercase:

```
window.gtmEventsDataLayer = [{
    "selector":".gtm-reply-begin",
    "domevent":"click",
    "gtmevent":"R2SEmailBegin",
    "gtmlabel":null
}];
```

I'm not even sure if it's an issue with Thymeleaf's inlining or my JSON serialization configuration (which is done by Jackson, since this is a Spring Boot application), but since it worked before migrating to Thymeleaf 3 I'm assuming it's something related to the new inlining implementation.

I also tried specifying `@JsonProperty("DOMEvent")` on the class properties, but in this case the javascript objects contain both the properly cased property and the lowercase one, which is not the optimal solution.

Is there some configuration I'm missing to force Thymeleaf to preserve the case when rendering javascript objects?

Comment: What do you see when you return and output the list(without inlining)? Are the properties lowercased in that too? By this you can determine if the case change is done by jackson or thymleaf.